How to make Azure Pipeline manual build choose git branch I want
My Azure pipeline uses 3 repos that we specify in the resources section.  But when I manually do a pipeline build from the Azure website, it seems to ignore the branch I choose on the web interface.  It always builds the 'master' branch of all 3 repos.  I want at least one of them to select the branch I specify
The build variable BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME is set properly by Azure to the branch I chose.  But it is ignored when the code is pulled.  How may I make my desired branch be selected?.
Here is my resources section
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Main
      type: git
      name: Software/Main
    - repository: SdkThirdParty
      type: git
      name: Software/SdkThirdParty
    - repository: SdkTestData
      type: git
      name: Software/SdkTestData

I know that I can make it select a branch if I hard code- it into these repository directives with a "ref" line.  So, if I wanted branch "my-test-branch" I could do this
- repository: Main
  type: git
  name: Software/Main
  ref: 'refs/heads/my-test-branch'

But I have to hard-code it.  I cannot use build variables in the resources section.  They are not supported there
So how can I variably choose which branch is pulled?


how can I variably choose which branch is pulled?

Using pipeline parameter, as suggested in Rui's answer, is a way to solve the issue if the branches to be selected remain constant.
However, if the branch names change frequently, this method requires you to continuously maintain the value of the pipeline parameter in your yaml.
In this case, you can choose the branch of each repo resources when you click the Run pipeline button, as Daniel mentioned. This way you will not need to maintain the value of the pipeline parameter.
Screenstoot：


This should be the accepted answer. I actually didn't know that it's possible to choose the branch for each repository resource, when queuing a new build.

I didn't know it either.  In fact I had never even noticed that "Resources" section of the "Run Pipeline" dialog.  Thanks

However one thing about your answer confuses me.  You say that under Rui's approach, changing the value would require me to edit the YAML.  But  Rui's answer chooses the branch based on a build variable, something I thought was not possible.  So if that is possible, then even under his approach as long as I choose a different value for that build variable, I should be able to switch branches at will without editing YAML, shouldn't I?

Hi @Joe, in Rui's answer, he shared two ways, the first way is to use the predefined variable Build.SourceBranch. In this way, the branch of the repository resources will be the same as the self-repo where your YAML is in, and you can switch branches without editing YAML.

The second is to use pipeline parameter. With this approach, you need maintain the value of the pipeline parameter in your YAML when you have created more branches in the repository resources. For example, if you created a branch named test20240711 today, you need to add it to the pipeline parameter value list in your YAML. Then you can choose it in the parameter value.

Hi @Joe, glad to hear that the answer helps! Happy coding!

As per Template Expressions in Repository Resource Definition, template expressions are supported when defining the ref property of a repository resource in a YAML pipeline.
Example - using a predefined variable:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Main
      type: git
      name: Software/Main
      ref: ${{ variables['Build.SourceBranch'] }}

Note:

Build.SourceBranch and Build.SourceBranchName are available in templates, as mentioned in predefined variables.

Example - using a pipeline parameter:
parameters:
  - name: branch
    type: string
    default: refs/heads/my-test-branch
    values:
      - refs/heads/my-dev-branch
      - refs/heads/my-test-branch
      - refs/heads/my-other-branch

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: Main
      type: git
      name: Software/Main
      ref: ${{ parameters.branch }}


When you queue a pipeline, you can choose the branch under the "resources" section of the queue screen. You don't need to use parameters.

@DanielMann I actually didn't know about it, thanks.

Using parameters can be used to restrict the branches that can be used, though.
